# Cannot resolve symbol "Object","v","parent" (parse.com getItemView())

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have gotten this code from the parse.com Android Developers Guide:

```
@Override
public View getItemView(ParseObject object, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
  if (v == null) {
    v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.adapter_item, null);
  }

  // Take advantage of ParseQueryAdapter's getItemView logic for
  // populating the main TextView/ImageView.
  // The IDs in your custom layout must match what ParseQueryAdapter expects
  // if it will be populating a TextView or ImageView for you.
  super.getItemView(object, v, parent);

  // Do additional configuration before returning the View.
  TextView descriptionView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.description);
  descriptionView.setText(object.getString("description"));
  return v;
}
```

However, `(ParseObject object, View v, ViewGroup parent)` has three errors:

```
Cannot resolve symbol "Object"
Cannot resolve symbol "v"
Cannot resolve symbol"parent"
```

Of course, I know I have to define object,v, and parent somewhere. But where? What are `PaseObject object`,`View v`,`ViewGroup parent` for? And how and where do I define them?
What I'm doing in my app is:

- I have a ParseQueryAdapter, and I want to customize it
- I want to customize it by adding a `description` textView, and making the font size bigger of the title. I have added the layout and everything. Now I want the code.

So, basically, where and how do I define `(ParseObject object, View v, ViewGroup parent)`?
**note: I have the parse library and everything;I can use ParseObject, etc.**
**Edit: Build.Gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.alibdeir.signupactivity"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.+"
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.+'
    compile 'com.baoyz.swipemenulistview:library:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.parse:parseui-widget-android:0.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0-rc1'
}
```

**Another edit:** I know I am doing a pretty lame mistake, but please, if you have an answer, answer. Even if you have to go into details. It would be great If I could finish this screen of my app I'm working on
**Full source:**

```
        package com.alibdeir.signupactivity;

    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.parse.FindCallback;
    import com.parse.GetDataCallback;
    import com.parse.LogOutCallback;
    import com.parse.ParseClassName;
    import com.parse.ParseException;
    import com.parse.ParseFile;
    import com.parse.ParseImageView;
    import com.parse.ParseObject;
    import com.parse.ParseQuery;
    import com.parse.ParseQueryAdapter;
    import com.parse.ParseUser;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    private Dialog progressDialog;
    ListView list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //region emailNotVerified
        if (user.getBoolean("emailVerified") == false) {
            Intent goBackToLogin = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(goBackToLogin);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please verify your email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
        //endregion
        else {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
            list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> titles = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(this, "Campaign");
            titles.setTextKey("Title");
            titles.setImageKey("Picture");

        }
        @Override
        public View getItemView(ParseObject object, View v, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (v == null) {
                v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.list_single, null);
            }

            super.getItemView(meal, v, parent);

            ParseImageView mealImage = (ParseImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            ParseFile photoFile = meal.getParseFile("photo");
            if (photoFile != null) {
                mealImage.setParseFile(photoFile);
                mealImage.loadInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                        // nothing to do
                    }
                });
            }

            TextView titleTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            titleTextView.setText(meal.getTitle());
            TextView ratingTextView = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.favorite_meal_rating);
            ratingTextView.setText(meal.getRating());
            return v;
        }







            // Take advantage of ParseQueryAdapter's getItemView logic for
            // populating the main TextView/ImageView.




        }


//        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
//        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
//        MenuInflater  menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_logout:
                openAlert();

                break;



        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void openAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Confirm your logout")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to log out?");
        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // Positive OnClick to log out
                showProgressBar("Logging Out");
                ParseUser.logOutInBackground(new LogOutCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            //Success
                            dismissProgressBar();
                            Intent startLogin = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                            MainActivity.this.startActivity(startLogin);
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            //Sign up did not succeed.
                            dismissProgressBar();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "An unknown error occurred while logging out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    }
                });
                ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
            }
        });
        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // Cancel
            }
        });
        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        // show alert
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    public void showProgressBar(String msg) {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Logging out", "Loading", true);
    }

    public void dismissProgressBar() {
        if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing())
            progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

}


**Don't worry about the file names and IDs, they are all correct**
```

Comment: As I am getting you have not added parse library to project , try adding parse library successfully .

Comment: @AndroidDev Dude, I can use everything else in PArse. I have 5 other activities that include signUp, creation of objects, log in, etc.

Comment: Can you include build.gradle .?

Comment: @AndroidDev Can I facepalm? I'll do it just so you can actually think about the problem

Comment: Remove parse related compile urls from dependencies and sync project , again paste the same urls and sync .

Comment: @AndroidDev are you kidding me? I feel like you're just spamming me. This is android development were taking about, it builds everytime you run your app. Removing your links is just like rebuilding the app.

Comment: @AndroidDev Did you even read my code and look for errors? I have a lame mistake I cannot find, if you're just as new as me please stop extending this conversation for no reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables are defined already, in the method definition, e.g. this:

```
public View getItemView(ParseObject object, View v, ViewGroup parent)
```

is what is declaring those variables. If you are getting an error that they are not defined, it must be because you're trying to access them from outside the getItemView() method or you renamed them in your actual code.

With your update showing the full source for the class that is defining this function, the problem is clear:

The `getItemView` method you are trying to override here is not a method defined by `AppCompatActivity` -- it's a method of `ParseQueryAdapter`.  I do not know how you ended up in this situation, but this method is not going to work in that class.  It must be moved to a new class that inherits from `ParseQueryAdapter`.

So, you'll need to have to have a class, lets say it's a Campaign, you need to subclass your `ParseQueryAdapter` with something like this:

```
 import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.TextView;


import com.parse.GetDataCallback;
import com.parse.ParseClassName;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseFile;
import com.parse.ParseImageView;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseUser;

/**
 * Created by AbAppletic on 12/15/2015.
 */
@ParseClassName("Campaign")

public class Campaign extends ParseObject {
    public Campaign() {
        // default Constructor
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return getString("Title");
//get the title
    }

    public String getDescription(){
//get the description
        return getString("Description");
    }

    public ParseUser getAuthor() {
// get the author
        return getParseUser("Owner");
    }


    public ParseFile getImage() {
//get the image
        return getParseFile("Picture");
    }
}
```

And, now, you have to make a new class, that extends

```
ParseQueryAdapter<Campaign>
// Campaign is the class we previously created
```

So, in your case, here you would be setting the image, description, and title from your custom layout:

```
public class mainAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<Campaign> {
public mainAdapter(Context context){
    super(context,new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<Campaign>(){
        public ParseQuery<Campaign> create(){
            ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Campaign");
            query.orderByDescending("updatedAt");
            return query;
        }
    });
}
@Override
public View getItemView(Campaign campaign, View v, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (v == null) {
        v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.list_single, null);
    }

    super.getItemView(campaign, v, parent);

    ParseImageView campaignImage = (ParseImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    ParseFile photoFile = campaign.getParseFile("Picture");
    if (photoFile != null) {
        campaignImage.setParseFile(photoFile);

        campaignImage.loadInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                // nothing to do
            }
        });
    }

    TextView titleTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
    titleTextView.setText(campaign.getTitle());
    TextView descriptionTextView = (TextView) v
            .findViewById(R.id.description);
    descriptionTextView.setText(campaign.getDescription());
    return v;

}
```

}
Now, in your MainActivity:
Define this:

```
    private mainAdapter adapter;
// mainAdapter is the name of the class we just created that extends ParseQueryAdapter
```

And, into your `onCreate()`, just set your adapter to the listView:

```
adapter = new mainAdapter(this);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And on top of `Parse.initialize`:

```
ParseObject.registerSubclass(Campaign.class);
```

Campaign is the first class we just created.

Comment: Can you give me an example of an activity containing it? I am defining it correctly. AS is just saying "`Cannot resolve symbol object`" and "`Cannot resolve symbol v`" and "`Cannot resolve symbol parent`"

Comment: Also, should I just put the above mentioned code *(In the question)* in the MainActivity.java file? Or should I make a separate activity extending View or something

Comment: That code belongs in your adapter (the class you created, inheriting from ParseQueryAdapter, if you are using the parse.com tutorial).  Android studio can't be producing those errors inside that method -- so where are the errors being indicated?  You must be trying to use 'object', 'v', etc somewhere outside the scope of the method.

Comment: I only have my `MainActivity`. That's all. What classes do I have to create and how? Please edit  your post.

Comment: You may only have one Activity, but that Activity certainly has multiple **methods** (aka functions -- `getItemView(...` is a function).  Those variables are only available within that function and nowhere else.  Can you please provide the full source code for your class?

Comment: Where is your `ParseQueryAdapter` class??  You're overriding `getItemView` on an `AppCompatActivity` but that class has no such method.

Comment: Thanks, but I solved it myself. And you're answer is correct. I need my `ParseQueryAdapter` class. Thanks. I will edit your question, and I will edit it to the way I fixed my problem :)

Comment: I would +1 if I could, but sorry. Low rep xD